# IE hang troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

On some pages of my WebApp IE hangs with message `Example page is not responding due to a long running script` but I can't troubleshoot it since Developer Tools panel hangs as well and does not respond.

I have IE 11.

How do you troubleshoot this kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post from the IE team's former program manager which describes exactly how to deal with your situation:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/01/15/debugging-internet-explorer-with-windbg.aspx

They're not as simple as you would expect since you will need to use tools such as WinDbg but definitely adds some knowledge in your arsenal